# Probability of seeing a certain sequence of results within a larger set of event results

Tags: probability, permutations

If I have an independent event `E` with two possible outcomes `x` and `y` with their own probabilities `p(x)` and `p(y)` and I then repeat event `E` a certain number of times (`n`), how can I calculate the probability of that sample of `n` events containing at least one sequence of consecutive identical results at least `L` occurrences long?

So for example, if I roll a fair 6 sided die each morning and consider it a "win" when I roll 5 or 6, how do I calculate the chances that if I do this for a year, I will have at least 9 "wins" in a row at some point?

So in my above example:

```
E: Rolling a fair six-sided die
x: Rolling 5 or 6
y: Rolling 1, 2, 3 or 4
p(x): 1/3
p(y): 2/3
n: 365
L: 9
```

Can I show for any values of these variables how to determine the probability of there being at least one instance of `L` consecutive occurrences of `x` within my `n` quantity of trials of `E`?

Comment: Easiest is probably to do it recursively.  Your sequence must begin with one of $y, xy, x^2y, \cdots, x^L$ where $y$ is anything other than a "win".  If you get $x^L$ at the start you can stop, with any of the others you restart with a shorter sequence.

Comment: Thank you yes, that other question does look like it is the same, apologies for the dupe. I will also take a look at the recursive solution suggested by lulu.